# Getting an Exception while calling some async methods from outside the class

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-5.0

lets say i have  class  called x and y like this

```
class x
{
    public x()
    {
         p();
    }
    private async p()
    {
      await q();
    }
    private async p()
    {
     //some logic is there  
    }
}
```

in test.aspx.cs file

i am trying to create an instance of this class

```
            x object =new x();
```

when i run this i get an exception at runtime  saying  :

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.

can any body explain me why ?

Comment: Have you marked the page as async as the message says? (And what is the *type* of the exception?)

Comment: The code doesn't seem to be ASP.NET, but the error message is. How do you call this code?

Comment: @Richard no ,  i didn't as a matter of fact an d i dont even know how to as i am new to (Completely new  //just started today )

Comment: Read the text of the exception: it tells you how.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman yes you are write  actually i am writing a  wrapper class kind of thing which will be used in asp.net page ...the above code is just for describing my situaiton  ... i made some changes to the  questions

Comment: When you can, please add your own answer and accept it. This better records, for future visitors, the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution (that is i followed the instruction the [@Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67392/richard) gave )

and added `Async="true"` to my aspx page in side the Page tag(the one that looks like this   `<%@ Page %>` )

and it worked !